# Практикум по языку Python

Tags: python, книги

Может ли кто поделиться таким? Помнится по Perl были классные мини задачки на "изюминки" языка, коих там предостаточно, хотелось бы что-нибудь подобное, чтоб усваивались знания получше.

Answer (score 3):

[pythontutor.ru](http://pythontutor.ru) - сайт с выполнением заданий онлайн

http://informatics.mccme.ru/course/view.php?id=156 - учебный курс с возможностью сдачи задач

Answer (score 3):

*Вот небольшой список интересных проектов, которые попадались мне на просторах Сети:*

https://www.talentbuddy.co/ - неплохой ресурс для тренировки решения задач на разных языках, в том числе и Python.

http://www.checkio.org/ - хороший ресурс с задачами, на котором можно даже получить комментарий от Гвидо ван Россума. Процесс решения геймифицирован.

https://projecteuler.net/ - сайт с набором задач различной сложности, решаешь на любом из языков, вводишь ответ в textbox, затем попадаешь на форум, где можно запостить своё крутое решение и посмотреть, как решалась задача другими людьми.

https://codecombat.com/ - rpg, для прохождения которой надо писать код на Python.

https://www.udacity.com/course/design-of-computer-programs--cs212 - курс по программированию с интересными задачами, теория + практика Python.

http://www.codecademy.com/ - любопытный сайт с задачами по разным языкам программирования, в том числе и Python